# If condition in Razor cshtml file

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a simple situation where Im trying to have three different span based on the results in a field in my index field.
So I have the following code

```
    @if (item.REF_Status.Result == "A")
    {


        <span class="label label-sm label-success"> Passed</span>

    }
</td>
```

However this eves me the error "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`" However, I changed the if condition to `@if(1==1)`  and the result was as i expected with every row getting the "passed" span. So the error seems to be with comparing the condition.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Share your cshtml full code or parts where is item's and  item.REF_status types shown

Comment: Because either `item` or `REF_Status` is `null`